# C# Create RSACryptoServiceProvider from public certificate key which is string

Tags: c#

Is it possible to generate RSACryptoServiceProvider from public cert key which is string.

I try like:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var publicKey = PublicKey.GetPublicKey();
provider.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + publicKey + "</Modulus></RSAKeyValue>");
```

but i get exception that is not valid base64

```
  at Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Couldn't decode XML ---> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

First: Your closing tags are backwards...

```
</RSAKeyValue></Modulus>
```

should read

```
</Modulus></RSAKeyValue>
```

Second: You're missing the exponent parameter.

See this working code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
//var publicKey = PublicKey.GetPublicKey();
provider.FromXmlString(
    "<RSAKeyValue>"+
        "<Modulus>CmZ5HcaYgWjeerd0Gbt/sMABxicQJwB1FClC4ZqNjFHQU7PjeCod5dxa9OvplGgXARSh3+Z83Jqa9V1lViC7qw==</Modulus>"+
        "<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>"+
    "</RSAKeyValue>");
```

Comment: tahank you, you save my day :D

Answer (score 1):

In **.NET Core 3.0** and above you can do the following:

```cs
//create a RSACryptoServiceProvinder, sample use
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.FromXmlString(ConvertPublicKeyFromBase64(base64publicKey));

    //rest of the code
    ...
}

public string ConvertPublicKeyFromBase64(string publicKeyBase64)
{
    // Decode the Base64 public key into a byte array
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyBase64);

    // Create an RSA object to import the public key
    using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
    {
        // Import the public key bytes
        rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKeyBytes, out _);

        // Export the public key as an XML string
        string publicKeyXml = rsa.ToXmlString(false);

        return publicKeyXml;
    }
}
```

For **.NET Framework**, there is no ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() method so you can use [this](https://github.com/jpassing/dotnet-crypto-utils/blob/master/CryptoUtils/RSAExtensions.cs) RSAExtensions Class that provides the ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() for it, and then use the code above.

[GitHub code for RSAExtensions](https://github.com/jpassing/dotnet-crypto-utils/blob/master/CryptoUtils/RSAExtensions.cs)
[RSAExtensions for .NET Framework article](https://jpassing.com/2021/12/05/importing-rsa-public-keys-in-downlevel-dotnet-and-dotnet-framework-versions/)